# How to call AsyncTask by the end of an AsyncTask from other Class

Tags: android, android-asynctask, odata

I have a class which is designated to consume Odata services, so i created 4 differents classes with async task but 'im not sure if them are created properly(correct),

so i create my main class which are update activity, this one start one AsyncTask, and pop-up a progress dialog ("connecting to server") by the end of this class on the post execute method, i wanna start my subsequent AsyncTasks but i'm not getting 
"I already tried couple solutions that i found here, such as calling the async test by calling the class after the post execute but i didn't get success", any one can help ?"

"I guess i created my async classes in a wrong way so anyone can give me a direction"

Update Activity :

```
atualiza_base = (Button) findViewById(R.id.update_button);
    atualiza_base.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            new callService().execute();

        }
    });
}

public class callService extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, String> {

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progress = ProgressDialog.show(Atualizar_Dados.this, "Aguarde...", "Conectando ao SMP", true, true);

    }

    protected String doInBackground(Object... params) {
        return URL;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        progress.dismiss();
        AtualizaClientes atualizaClientes = new AtualizaClientes();
        atualizaClientes.callServiceClientes.execute();


    }
}
```

One of my 4 AsyncTasks which are the same, with differents services only that...

```
public class AtualizaClientes extends Atualizar_Dados {
ClienteDAO sqlObjCliente;
private ProgressDialog progressC;
ArrayList<OEntity> zmob_kunnr;

ListView listCliente;

 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    sqlObjCliente = new ClienteDAO(AtualizaClientes.this);

    class callServiceCliente extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<OEntity>> {
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            progressC = ProgressDialog.show(AtualizaClientes.this, "Aguarde...", "Atualizando Clientes", true, true);
        }

        public ArrayList<OEntity> doInBackground(Void... params) {
            ODataConsumer ccli = ODataJerseyConsumer.create(URL);
            List<OEntity> listEntitiesKunnr = ccli.getEntities("ZMOB_KUNNRSet").execute().toList();

            System.out.println("Size" + listEntitiesKunnr.size());

            for (OEntity entityKunnr : listEntitiesKunnr) {
                zmob_kunnr.add(entityKunnr);
            }
            return zmob_kunnr;
        }

        @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<OEntity> kunnr) {
            super.onPostExecute(kunnr);
            try {
                sqlObjCliente.open();
                sqlObjCliente.deleteCliente();

                for (int k = 0; k < zmob_kunnr.size(); k++) {
         sqlObjCliente.insertCliente(zmob_kunnr.get(k).getProperty("Kunnr").getValue().toString().toUpperCase(), 
                                     zmob_kunnr.get(k).getProperty("Name1").getValue().toString().toUpperCase());
                }
                sqlObjCliente.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }

            progressC.dismiss();
            // new callServiceMaterial().execute();
            //new callServiceProblema();
        }
    }

}
```

Any helps will be appreciated, thanks...

Answer (score 0):

To call AsyncTask from another AsyncTask which is at different class, just create a simple interface and manage your AsyncTask calls. Interfaces are good solution for it.

Comment: See sample code for interface, you will get Idea how it works between classes.

http://www.codemiles.com/java-examples/java-interface-example-t3505.html